# Give the negation of the statement $X→(Y \lor Z)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The instruction is to provide a statement using laws of logic that negates the given statement. The dilemma I'm having now is to whether show the negation sign (¬) in my answer or simplify the expression.

So, what I did is the following:

$X→(Y \lor Z)$

$¬[X→(Y \lor Z)] \space \space \space \space \space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$         *(assuming that this is what 'negation' means)*

$¬X→¬(Y \lor Z)$

$¬X→(¬Y ∧ ¬Z) \space \space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$        *(De Morgan's Law)*

$¬(¬Y ∧ ¬Z)  →¬(¬X) \space\space\space\space\space$  *(Contraposition)*

$(Y \lor Z) → X \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ *(De Morgan's + Double Negation)*

Is my solution correct? Is this what negation means?

Comment: You cannot distribute the negation across the implication like you did. Example: $(x=2) \rightarrow (x>1)$, but incorrectly distributing like you did would give $(x\ne 2) \rightarrow (x\le1)$

Comment: Recall that $A\to B$ is the same as $  ¬ A\:  V\: B$

Answer (score 1):

Your third line is incorrect. The negation $\neg (X\rightarrow (Y \lor Z) )$ is equivalent to $X \wedge \neg(Y \lor Z) $ which is precisely $X \wedge \neg Y \wedge \neg Z$.

Comment: I would add the explanation that what you wrote is true because $A \rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg (A \wedge \neg B)$, in case the OP doesn’t know that.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\neg(X \implies (Y \lor Z))\\
\neg(\neg X \lor (Y \lor Z))\\
\neg(\neg X \lor Y \lor Z)\\
X \land \neg Y \land \neg Z
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

An *implication is false* exactly when *its antecedent is true* and *its consequent is false*.  $$\lnot(P\to Q)~~\iff~~ P\land \lnot Q$$

A *disjunction is false* exactly when *neither disjunct is true*.   $$\lnot(P\vee Q)~~\iff~~(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)$$